# Подключение Swagger и своей UI к REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, ui, swagger

Как подключить Swagger и свою UI к REST на один сервер на разные порты. Может кто видел какие гайды на эту тему? Также интересует вопрос как собственно подключить к REST проекту свою UI/ и заставить все это работать.

Comment: а на чем у вас UI?

Comment: ui написана на ангуляре

Comment: кладете UI на ангуляре в папку, раздаете как обычную статику.